# Specify which types of nodes spawn when?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, timer, sprite-kit

**I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked/answered, I didn't know how to word the title, much less the search.**

I'm making this iOS game where you have to tap to drop the player and hit the pillars below. I'm trying to implement "bad pillars"; pillars that if touched, will result in game over. Ideally, I'd like for the bad pillars to spawn in place of the good pillars, but they keep spawning on top of, or next to the them. Currently I have the good pillars, set up on a timer for an SKAction Array.

*Disregard any comments throughout my code, they need updating*

> add pillar function:

```
func addPillar(){

    let max = Double(UInt32.max)
    let randomInterval = ((Double(arc4random()) / max)+0.4) * 0.5



    // initiallize pillarArray as a shuffled array
    pillarArray = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: pillarArray) as! [String]
    // initiallize pillar node to first item in shuffled pillarArray
    pillar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: pillarArray[0])



    // set pillar position as a random integer between lowestValue , highestValue
    let pillarPosition = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: Int(-self.frame.height / 2) , highestValue: Int((-self.frame.height / 2) + 40 ))

    let position = CGFloat(pillarPosition.nextInt())

    pillar.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - 10, y: (position));

    // set pillar physics body

    pillar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: pillar.size)
    pillar.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false;
    pillar.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = pillarBitMask
    pillar.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerBitMask
    pillar.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerBitMask
    //pillar.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.80
    pillar.physicsBody?.friction = 10



    // add a new pillar node to the scene

    if(!isPaused){
        self.addChild(pillar)
    }

        // an array of type SKAction
        var animArray = [SKAction]()

        // append a move sequence to the array for "time" seconds.


        if(timerIsRunning && isPaused == true){
            animArray.append(SKAction.stop())
        }
        animArray.append(SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(Double(randomInterval))))

        animArray.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -self.frame.size.width + 5, y: pillar.position.y), duration: 4))



        // run the sequence
        animArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
        pillar.run(SKAction.sequence(animArray))
```

> timer to control when the pillars are spawned:

```
pausedTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: #selector (pauseTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

As for the bad pillars I have it set up the same way as the regular pillars, i.e. a bad pillar function, array, and timer, except I've been trying to fiddle with the timing but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want to.

Is there any method in SKAction Array, or just in general, that can allow me to pick what gets spawned when without having to create another array/timer/function?

Let me know I need to supply additional code, or provide clarification. Thanks

Comment: Can you state the effect you would like to achieve?

Comment: I stated this in the first paragraph of my question. Ideally, I'd like the bad pillars to randomly spawn in place of some of the good pillars. Currently, because I have the good and bad pillars operating independently of each other (on separate timers), the bad pillars just spawn on, or next to, the good pillars

Comment: Got it. You should have one timer (or repeating SKAction sequence) which spawns either a good or bad pillar.

Comment: I've tried that by simply adding the image name of the bad pillar to the  good pillar array,  but the system just recognizes them as good pillars regardless of whether they are or aren't. I also don't want the bad pillars to spawn as many times as the good pillars; I want the bad pillars' spawn rate to be fairly low.

Comment: Timer does not work with spritekit all the time. check out Skaction.wait